# How to exclude a company-backend from autocompleting without globally removing it

Tags: company-mode

I would like to be able to prevent company mode from automatically suggesting a specific backend (namely `company-dabbrev)` when in a specific mode (using `text-mode-hook`), however I don't want want to remove this backend from `company-backends` as I still want to include to get its completions when I manually invoke `company-complete-common-or-cycle`.

So, how would I go about excluding a backend from autocompleting on text input without excluding it entirely from `company-backends`?

(The motivation for this is that I find autocompletion on arbitrary words I'm typing in a text document distracting, but I do want to keep autocompletions such as latex environments, as these are quite handy. I do however sometimes want manual autocompletion for when I'm typing a long word that I've forgotten how to spell, but I know I've typed before.)

Answer (score 6):

see https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues/112 @dgutov comment.

Make the `company-dabbrev` the last element in `company-backends`.
completion of previous backends will block company-dabbrev.

I usually place `company-ispell` at the beginning of the `company-backends` in `text-mode-hook` which blocks other backends in most cases.

If your want to remove/add backends instead of tweaking the priority of backends.

```
(defun company-my-setup ()
  (when (boundp 'company-backends)
    (make-local-variable 'company-backends)
    ;; remove
    (setq company-backends (delete 'company-dabbrev company-backends))
    ;; add
    (add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-dabbrev)))

(add-hook 'latex-major-mode-hook 'company-my-setup)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I see how tweaking the priority of backends can achieve this. Say I'm typing the word "hello", I don't want any backend to succeed for any portion of the word, so none should succeed, and consequently, none will block `company-dabbrev` when placed at the end.

Comment: And the other strategy, it seems like this still doesn't selectively remove the backends for the context of completing a half-typed word but not for calling something with say `company-complete`? Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I updated the last code snippet , just delete/add 'company-dabbrev. If you want to turn off all backends, `(setq company-backends nil)`